# JSON to JavaScript Array and use in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm in the learning process of JS and my teacher has given us an asignment where we shall use info from a JSON file in our JS.

Problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to convert the JSON to variables/arrays in javascript so I can use it in my existing JS code.

My JSON looks like this:

```
    "id": 0,
    "albumName":"Greatest hits",
    "artistName":"ZZ-top",
    "artistWebsite":"http://www.zztop.com/",
    "productionYear": 1992,     
    "trackList":[
        {
            "trackNumber":1,
            "trackTitle":"Gimme all your lovin'",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":241
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":2, 
            "trackTitle":"sharp dressed man",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":256
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":3,
            "trackTitle":"Rough boy",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":290
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":4,
            "trackTitle":"Tush",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":135
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":5,
            "trackTitle":"My head's in Mississippi",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":261
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":6,
            "trackTitle":"Pearl Necklace",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":246
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":7,
            "trackTitle":"I'm bad, I'm nationwide",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":287
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":8,
            "trackTitle":"Viva Las Vegas",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":288
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":9,
            "trackTitle":"Doubleback",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":236
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":10,
            "trackTitle":"Gun Love",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":220
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":11,
            "trackTitle":"Got me under pressure",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":241
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":12,
            "trackTitle":"Give it up",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":210
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":13,
            "trackTitle":"Cheap sunglasses",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":287
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":14,
            "trackTitle":"Sleeping bag",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":244
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":15,
            "trackTitle":"Planet of women",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":246
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":16,
            "trackTitle":"La Grange",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":233
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":17,
            "trackTitle":"Tube snake boogie",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":185
        },

        {
            "trackNumber":18,
            "trackTitle":"Legs-remix version",
            "trackTimeInSeconds":272
        }
    ]
},
```

And I need it to go into this var:

```
    artistName : "ArtistName",
    albumName : "AlbumName",
    noOfTracks : 0,
    prodYear : 9999,
    trackList : "",

    init : function(artistName, albumName, noOfTracks, prodYear, trackList ){
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.albumName = albumName;
        this.noOfTracks = noOfTracks;
        this.prodYear = prodYear;
        this.trackList = trackList;

        return this;
    },
```

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) might be a start...

Comment: Look at section marked `methods` at that link in particular.

Comment: What you have given is not correct JSON data. Correct JSON data must be enclosed in {} or [] so it represents JS array or object and can be parsed by simple `eval`, which is not recommended though. You should get correct JSON data (or 'repair' it yourself) and use `JSON.parse` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First make a string :

```
var ab = JSON.stringify(...);  // pass your json here
```

Note: Try this on console.

Then make an object :

```
var ac = JSON.parse(ab);
```

now you have an JavaScript object and you can access with :

```
    ac.artistName = artistName;
    ac.albumName = albumName;
    ac.noOfTracks = noOfTracks;
    ac.prodYear = prodYear;
    ac.trackList = trackList;
```

hope this helps. :)